# Strange numerical integration result

Tags: numerical-integration

I write a function called `berrycur[kx,ky]` which I will give at the end of the question, and want to numerically integrate this function over {kx, -2π, 2π]}, {ky, 0, 4π/Sqrt[3]}.
The plot of `berrycur` is shown as follows:

[image]

I have checked that all values of `berrycur` in this region is positive. But the numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[ berrycur[kx, ky][[1]], {kx, -2π, 2π]}, {ky, 0, 4π/Sqrt[3]}]
```

**gives result is zero !!!! This is absolutely wrong!!**

Actually, the NIntegrate result of {kx, -2π, 0]}, {ky, 0, 4π/Sqrt[3]} is opposite to NIntegrate result of {kx, 0, 2π]}, {ky, 0, 4π/Sqrt[3]}, this is strange!

**What is wrong here?**

---

the definition of `berrycur` is

```
Clear[h]
h[kx_, ky_] := {{0.1` (-4 Cos[(Sqrt[3] ky)/2] Sin[kx/2] + 2 Sin[kx]), 
   E^((I ky)/Sqrt[3]) + 
    E^(-(1/6) I (3 kx + Sqrt[3] ky)) (1 + E^(I kx))}, {E^(-((I ky)/
     Sqrt[3])) + 
    E^(-(1/6) I (3 kx - Sqrt[3] ky)) (1 + E^(
       I kx)), -0.1` (-4 Cos[(Sqrt[3] ky)/2] Sin[kx/2] + 2 Sin[kx])}}
dim = Length@h[1, 1];
Clear[hpar1, hpar2];
hpar1[kx_, ky_] = D[h[kx, ky], kx];
hpar2[kx_, ky_] = D[h[kx, ky], ky];
Clear[purifyeigs];
purifyeigs[eigs_] := 
  Transpose@Sort@Transpose@{Re[eigs[[1]]], eigs[[2]]};

Clear[berrycur];
berrycur[kxkx_?NumericQ, kyky_?NumericQ] := Module[{eigs},
  eigs = purifyeigs@Eigensystem[h[kxkx, kyky]];
  Table[Im@
    Sum[((Conjugate[eigs[[2, i]]].hpar1[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
            j]])*(Conjugate[eigs[[2, j]]].hpar2[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
            i]]) - (Conjugate[eigs[[2, i]]].hpar2[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2,
             j]])*(Conjugate[eigs[[2, j]]].hpar1[kxkx, kyky].eigs[[2, 
            i]]))/(eigs[[1, i]] - eigs[[1, j]])^2, {j, 
      DeleteCases[Range[1, dim], i]}], {i, 1, dim}]
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your use of `Part` to extract a single value from the result of `berrycur` is  causing `NIntegrate` to symbolically integrate your function.  Try evaluating the indefinite integral for a clue as to what is going on, e.g.

```
Integrate[berrycur[x, y][[1]], x, y]
```

> (x^2 y)/2

If you clean-up your function definition to return a single value:

```
berrycur2[kxkx_?NumericQ, kyky_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{eigs, i = 1, j = 2}, 
  eigs = purifyeigs@Eigensystem[h[kxkx, kyky]];
  Im@((Conjugate[eigs[[2, i]]].hpar1[kxkx, 
          kyky].eigs[[2, j]])*(Conjugate[eigs[[2, j]]].hpar2[kxkx, 
          kyky].eigs[[2, i]]) - (Conjugate[eigs[[2, i]]].hpar2[kxkx, 
          kyky].eigs[[2, j]])*(Conjugate[eigs[[2, j]]].hpar1[kxkx, 
          kyky].eigs[[2, i]]))/(eigs[[1, i]] - eigs[[1, j]])^2]
```

Then you obtain

```
NIntegrate[berrycur2[x, y], {y, 0, 4 π/Sqrt[3]}, {x, -2 π, 2 π}]
```

> 12.5664

Which looks more reasonable.

Comment: Hi, MikeLimaOscar! Great explanation! How did you come up with the idea to test `Integrate[berrycur[x, y][[1]], x, y]`? This explains the unreasonable result. But I still want to know why `Integrate` gives `(x^2 y)/2`??? It seems that `(x^2 y)/2` is the integration of `x y` in terms of x.

Comment: What is more, the integration of `berrycur` is rather slow, it tooks me 40 seconds to give result 12.5664. Do you know how to speed it up?

Comment: @matheorem Try `Integrate[berrycur[x,y][[1]],x,y]//Trace`.  You'll see that Mathematica ends up with an integrand of `x`.

Comment: ...as for speeding it up, all I can suggest is you look at the documentation for [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html) and experiment with the various [rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! `Trace` is so useful!

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Table in berrycur,and then change to berrycur[kxkx_?NumericQ, kyky_?NumericQ, i_]

```
NIntegrate[berrycur[kx, ky, 1], {kx, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {ky, 0, 4 \[Pi]/Sqrt[3]}]
```

> 12.5664